# What's wrong with this shell/sed script?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have about 150 HTML files in a given directory that I'd like to make some changes to. Some of the anchor tags have an href along the following lines: `index.php?page=something`. I'd like all of those to be changed to `something.html`. Simple regex, simple script. I can't seem to get it correct, though. Can somebody weigh in on what I'm doing wrong?

Sample html, before and after output:

```
<!-- Before -->
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=dandelion">Dandelion</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=elephant">Elephant</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=resonate">Resonate</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- After -->
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="dandelion.html">Dandelion</a></li>
    <li><a href="elephant.html">Elephant</a></li>
    <li><a href="resonate.html">Resonate</a></li>
</ul>
```

Script file:

```
#! /bin/bash

for f in *.html
do
    sed s/\"index\.php?page=\([.]*\)\"/\1\.html/g < $f >! $f
done
```

Comment: Other than using a regex to process HTML?

Comment: What is `>!`? I've never see this... Also, you might want to know about `sed`'s `-i` option.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't think this qualifies as processing HTML with regexp.  It's a simple line substitution.

Comment: As a side note, replacing the ugliness of bash, sed, awk, et al. is one of the express design purposes of Perl. If you can already stomach bash *and* sed, then bash and Perl is much nicer: `perl -pi -e's/"index\.php?page=(.*)"/\1.html/g' $f`. See? You don't even have to redirect.

Comment: @though, in a perl regex, `?` is a special char, so you have to escape it otherwise you'll never find a match. Also, use `$1` in the replacement instead of `\1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your regex, and the fact that the shell is trying to interpret bits of your regex.

First - the `[.]*` matches any number of literal dots `.`. Change it to `.*`.

Secondly, enclose the entire regex in single quotes `'` to prevent the bash shell from interpreting any of it.

```
sed 's/"index\.php?page=\(.*\)"/\1\.html/g'
```

Also, instead of `< $f >! $f` you can just feed in the '-i' switch to sed to have it operate in-place:

```
sed -i 's/"index\.php?page=\(.*\)"/"\1\.html"/g' "$f"
```

(Also, as another point I think in your replacement you want double quotes around the `\1.html` so that the new URL is quoted within the HTML. I also quoted your `$f` to `"$f"`, because if the file name contains spaces bash will complain).

**EDIT**: as @TimPote notes, the standard way to match something within quotes is either `".*?"` (so that the `.*` is non-greedy) or `"[^"]+"`. Sed doesn't support the former, so try:

```
sed -i 's/"index\.php?page=\([^"]\+\)"/"\1\.html"/g' "$f"
```

This is to prevent (for example) `<a href="index.php?page=asdf">"asdf"</a>` from being turned into `<a href="asdf">"asdf.html"</a>` (where the `(.*)` captured `asdf">"asdf`, being greedy).

Comment: way to go spoiling it for everybody!

Comment: Good explanation but your code doesn't work.  Your replacement text doesn't include `index.php...`.  Plus the `.*` is still too greedy.  Use `[^"]\+'.

Comment: @TimPote can you explain? When I try this on the input given in the OP  in bash, it does work (output matches that which the OP requires). good pickup on `[^"]\+`, I'll add a note.

Comment: @TimPote the code provided worked here (first one, without `-i`)

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Sorry dude, I misunderstood the question.  I thought the `index.php` stuff was supposed to stay there.  Even still, you would be better off using `[^"]\+` instead of `.*`.  Took away my downvote though since the answer works.  Sorry again.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I know, that's why I put the `"[^"]\+"` as the alternative. I'll edit the post to make it a bit clearer, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.*` was too greedy.  Use `[^"]\+` instead.  Plus your quotes were all messed up.  Surround the whole thing with single quotes instead, then you can use `"` without escaping them.

```
sed -i 's/"index\.php?page=\([^"]\+\)"/"\1\.html"/g'
```

You can do this whole operation with a single statement using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.html' \
 -exec sed -i 's/"index\.php?page=\([^"]\+\)"/"\1\.html"/g' {} \+
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to include `index.php etc` in the results, as per the posted question. Anyway, the `[^"]\+` part is the way to go, always!

Comment: @heltonbiker Yeah just realized that.  Answer changed.

Comment: That's incorrect. **Globbed** filenames is a *correct* way to loop on filenames. The key is to quote the variable: `sed ... "$file"` (which mathematical coffee didn't do). Your `find` command is another correct way.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thanks again for your watchful eye.  I'll learn one of these days...

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
 sed "s/\"index\.php?page=\(.*\)\"/\"\1.html\"/g" < 1.html
```

I think it was mostly the square brackets.  Not sure why you had them.
Oh, and the entire sed command needs to be in quotes.